# How to dinit all View Controller?

Tags: ios, swift, hierarchy

I want to remove all the running view controllers when user LogOut and navigate to `loginVC`.

my code:

```
  let nvcMain = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController()

    for view in (UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.subviews)!{
        view.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window!!.rootViewController = nvcMain
```

Its redirecting to the `LoginVC` but my other ViewControllers are still open.**(i checked that from debug view Hierarchy)** and consume memory.
so i want to remove all other `viewControllers`.
can anybody provide some solution or suggestions?

Comment: You don't have to remove all ViewController/Views from keywindow, rather simply reset your rootViewController that should do the job

Comment: i did that same...but debug view Hierarchy shows that are still open

Comment: I never faced this problem before but I believe u must be having a strong references to `ViewController` which is preventing them from deiniting

Answer (score 0):

You can use logout option like this :

```
let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let loginVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginVC") as! LoginVC
let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController:loginVC)
UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window!.rootViewController = nav
```

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: that do not make any difference.

Comment: I am using this in my project and works fine. Can you please explain more? So I will try to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

**Unwind segues**

When logout it's better to use **Unwind Segues** , it's very easy to implement.

Read this [article about unwind segues](https://medium.com/@mimicatcodes/create-unwind-segues-in-swift-3-8793f7d23c6f).